# Group by Datepart using total month daywise total orders

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

here this is my stored procedure.. per day how many new orders and oldo rders are there in overall month..
i was declare date,totalorders and revenue..

**result** i'm getting only last day of the month that is 31st.. i want daywise orders count..

```
alter Procedure sp_NewandOld
(
@StartDate  DATETIME,        
@EndDate  DATETIME
)
--[sp_NewandOld] '01/01/2015','01/31/2015'
AS 
BEGIN   
---New Customer Orders Breakup
Declare @NewCount int, @NewRevenue int, @NewDate nvarchar(50)
select @NewDate=(datepart(day,od.OrderDate)),
@NewCount= count(*), 
@NewRevenue= SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2),od.TotalAmount)) from orderdetails od 
inner join customer c on od.customerid=c.customerid 
where Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) = Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),c.registereddate,101))
and Convert(Datetime,convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by datepart(day, od.OrderDate)


Declare @OldCount int, @OldRevenue int, @OldDate nvarchar(50)
select @OldDate=(datepart(day,od.OrderDate)),
@OldCount= count(*), 
@OldRevenue=SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2),od.TotalAmount)) from orderdetails od 
inner join  customer c on od.customerid=c.customerid 
where Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) != Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),c.registereddate,101))
and Convert(Datetime,convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by datepart(day, od.OrderDate)

select @NewDate,@NewCount,@OldCount,@NewRevenue,@OldRevenue
End
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select only first-row-values into a variables, and you need to get all. Change your query to this to get all data:

```
alter Procedure sp_NewandOld (
    @StartDate  DATETIME,        
    @EndDate  DATETIME
)
AS 
BEGIN   

    with [new] as (
        select  datepart(month,od.OrderDate) as newdatemonth,
                datepart(day,od.OrderDate) as newdate,
                count(*) as NewCount, 
                SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2),od.TotalAmount)) as NewRevenue
        from orderdetails od 
        inner join customer c 
            on od.customerid=c.customerid 
        where Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) = Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),c.registereddate,101))
        and Convert(Datetime,convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) between @StartDate and @EndDate
        group by datepart(month,od.OrderDate), datepart(day, od.OrderDate)
    ), [old] as (
        select  datepart(month,od.OrderDate) as OldDateMonth,
                datepart(day,od.OrderDate) as OldDate,
                count(*) as OldCount, 
                SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2),od.TotalAmount)) as OldRevenue
        from orderdetails od 
        inner join customer c 
            on od.customerid=c.customerid 
        where Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) != Convert(Datetime,Convert(varchar(50),c.registereddate,101))
        and Convert(Datetime,convert(varchar(50),od.orderdate,101)) between @StartDate and @EndDate
        group by datepart(month,od.OrderDate) , datepart(day, od.OrderDate)
    )

    select  n.newdatemonth,
            n.NewDate,
            n.NewCount,
            o.OldCount,
            n.NewRevenue,
            o.OldRevenue
    from [new] n
    inner join [old] o
        on n.newdate = o.olddate and n.newdatemonth = o.OldDateMonth

End
```

Comment: its worikng but i wnat new count percent and old count percentage.. where should i mention???

Comment: you can add this to query, what formula you want to use?

Comment: I added total count per day above mentioned query..now  i want percent for new and old count per day... if new count:12,old:13,total:25,Now i want percent??? (12/30)*100??? is it correct???

Comment: (12/25)*100 I suppose

Comment: ((o.OldCount*100)/t.TotalCount) like this working.. i mentioned in the select statement...

Comment: My pleasure! If my post helps you be free to upvote/accept it! And good luck! :)

Comment: above query i'm getting only month data. i want every month data.. if i mentioned StartDate is "01-01-2015" and EndDate is "04-01-2015" . suggest me @gofr1

Comment: You want data from 1 of January till 1 o April, am I right? And what output you get using this SP?

Comment: same output.. but i want month wise also.. above mentioned query getting only month data

Comment: Ah! I eventually understand you :) See edits to answer, I add two fields that represent then month. If you need to count throw year you can add same fields with `datepart(year`

Comment: now i want to show month also..present i'm getting only day wise orders in that particular month. In my sp i'm getting only month data.. if i mentioned between 2 months its not working...

Comment: Really Thank you so much... i tried but not getting... Thank a lot...@gofr1

Comment: Once again - my pleasure! :)